# Pass Object (DF) to Custom Function Stored in Script

Tags: r

How do I pass a pre-existing object, such as a DF, to my custom functions, given the setup I have (see below)?
Alternatively, do I need to set up my custom functions differently?

My functions reside in a series of *.R scripts.
I source the functions in my .Rprofile:

```
.env$fxShortName <- function(){
source("C:\\path\\to\\scriptFile.R")
}
```

Not-Quite Solutions:

1) Defining the Function Manually || It works w/ the obvious drawback that I need to manually load my functions each time.
2) Rscript + commandArgs || This works if I define the DF within the function, like this:

```
#foo.R
a <- data.frame(a = c(1))
b <- data.frame(b = c(1))
args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)
print(args)
data.frame.name <- args[1]
print(colnames(get(data.frame.name)))
```

Rscript creates a new R instance, though, so it doesn't see my pre-existing DF.  At least, it doesn't find it out-of-the-box.
3) Function w/ substitute, match.call, etc. || I've adopted %>>% to set up auto-updated views of certain DFs, so I tried modifying the setup that works in that case.  For %>>% I have this code in my .Rprofile:

```
.env$`%>>%` <- function(expr, x) {
x <- substitute(x) 
call <- match.call()[-1] 
fun <- function() {NULL} 
body(fun) <- call$expr 
makeActiveBinding(sym = deparse(x), fun = fun, env = parent.frame())
invisible(NULL)
}
```

This type of setup works with DFs from my current session.  However, I prefer the structure offered by keeping my custom scripts separate from my .Rprofile.

4) get() & mget() || This seemed promising, but I don't understand it enough to definitively say whether or not it will help.  And, yes, I did RTFM.

Reproducible Example:

```
myfx(head, preExistingDF)
```

Sample Code:

```
myfx <- function(expr, x) {
x <- substitute(x)
call <- match.call()[-1]
fun <- function() {NULL}
body(fun) <- call$expr
print(body(fun))}
```

Put the sample code in a script.  Add the following code to your .Rprofile:

```
.env$mySamplefx <- function(){
source("C:\\path\\to\\myfx.R")
}
```

Then try it after adding the code directly to your .Rprofile.

Comment: I can't make any sense of this. You are just trying to pass a value to a function? You do that by passing the object as a parameter to the function. The problem you are trying to solve isn't very clear.

Comment: If by "value", you mean an entire DF, then yes. 

I know how to pass the DF to a function if the function is defined manually during the R session OR if it is defined completely in the .Rprofile (see point #1 and point #3 under "Not-Quite Solutions").

So, pass a value to a custom function when a) the body of the function is in an .R file and b) the function source()s the .R profile on startup in the .Rprofile.  That is, "My functions reside in a series of *.R scripts. I source the functions in my .Rprofile".